# Getting an out of list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

Not sure why it is going out of range.  I set the range from 0 to 5.
Here is my code

```
class Car(object):
    def __init__ (self, price, speed, fuel, mileage):
        self.price = price
        self.speed = speed
        self.fuel = fuel
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.price = price
        if price > 1000:
            self.tax = 15
        else:
            self.tax = 12
    def displayAll(self):
        print "Price: " + str(self.price)
        print "Speed: "  + str(self.speed) 
        print "Fuel: " + str(self.fuel)
        print "Mileage: " + str(self.mileage)
        print "Tax: 0." + str(self.mileage) 

auto = [5]
for car in range(0,5):
    price = input("How much does the car cost? ")
    speed = input("Mile per hour? ")
    mileage = input("Mile per gallon? ")
    fuel = raw_input("How much fuel? ")
    print car
    auto[car] = Car(price, speed, fuel, mileage)
```

Comment: Start with an empty list and use `append()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're just creating a list with one element `5` in it. A better way to write this code might be

```
auto = []
for car in range(0,5):
    price = input("How much does the car cost? ")
    speed = input("Mile per hour? ")
    mileage = input("Mile per gallon? ")
    fuel = raw_input("How much fuel? ")
    print car
    auto.append(Car(price, speed, fuel, mileage))
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto is a matrix of one entry, that is the number 5, i.e. [5].  You want it to instead be a matrix with 5 entries.

Answer (score 0):

You set auto to `auto=[5]` but it should be `auto=[None]*5` or `auto=range(5)`

otherwise you create a list of length 1 and will get an out of bounds error when calling `auto[car]`